# How to edit this html lexer rule?

Tags: html, regex, compiler-construction, tokenize, lexer

I want to edit this HTML lexer rule and I need help with the Regular Expression
the TAG_NAME refers to any HTML attribute for ex: (required, class, id, etc...).
I want to edit it to make it does not accept this exact syntax: 'az-'.
I think this needs regular expression modification, I looked it up but I couldn't integrate what I found online with the way these rules are written.
**I tried to remove the '-' in the Tag_NameChar as a first try but that made the HTML doesnt recognize attributes like 'data-target'.**

This snippet is for the rule:

[image]

and this one shows how the attributes are recognized.

[image]

Comment: " I want to edit it to make it does not accept this exact syntax: 'az-'" Does that mean you specifically don't want to allow the exact tag name `az-`, but say `ab-` would be okay? Or that you don't want to accept any name that ends with a dash? Or any name consisting of two letters followed by a dash? Or something else? "I couldn't integrate what I found online with the way these rules are written" What did you find online?

Comment: ab- would be okay 
I want az- exactly to be excluded
I am using antlr4
I found this regex: (?![enp])[a-z]
which excludes only letters from the a-z
I want to exclude a whole string

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65044060/how-to-edit-this-html-lexer-rule?noredirect=1#
this is the link i found

Answer (score 0):

ANTLR does not support lookahead syntax like some regex engines do, so there's no easy way to exclude certain matches from within the regex. It's always *possible* to rewrite a regular expression to exclude a given string (regular expressions are closed under negation and intersection), but it usually ends up quite painful. In your case, you'd end up with something following the logic of "a tag name can either have less than 3 characters, more than 3 characters, or it could have three characters where the first isn't an 'a', the second isn't a 'z' or the last isn't a '-'".

The less painful, but also less cross-language solution is to use a predicate that returns `false` if the text of the tag name equals `az-`. So something like `{getText().equals("az-")}?` depending on the language.

If you're okay with introducing an additional lexer rule, you may also introduce a rule `INVALID_TAG_NAME` (or whatever you want to call it) that matches exactly `az-` and that's defined before `TAG_NAME`. That way any tag that's named exactly `az-` will produce an `INVALID_TAG_NAME` token instead of a `TAG_NAME` token.

Depending on your requirements, you could also leave the grammar unchanged altogether and simply produce an error when you see a tag named `az-` when you traverse the tree in a listener or visitor.